# What is the text "i ´¢ówdm´¢ú: Compiled successfully" referring to when building an Angular/Core project in VS?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have a working project and though that I'd enjoy reading some logs to get a more solid understanding of the processes under the hood. Part of the logged info looks as follows. I'm curious about the last part saying that something compiled successfully. What does it refer to by that strange name: *i ´¢ówdm´¢ú*.

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:56190, open your browser on http://localhost:56190/ **
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         Date: 2019-04-11T07:57:18.612Z
>   Hash: 540c4e07ee5b7751841d
>   Time: 14221ms
>   chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 496 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 419 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
>   chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 437 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.52 MB [initial] [rendered]
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         i ´¢ówdm´¢ú: Compiled successfully.

I'm not sure where in the source code is set to run *ng build*, which apparently is the part that causes the log quoted above. I just noticed that it's there when I execute *dotnet watch run*.

Comment: Is this related? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55148

Comment: @MatthewWatson Can't tell for sure. On one hand, the formulation is weirdly similar. On the other hand, the post is from summer last year and it's claimed regard a bug that's already been fixed. Not sure at all...

Comment: Have you an idea of what happened ? Cause I'm having same '"issue" when i build my project. It doesn't seem to be a real problem but just wondering...

Comment: @KBell Regrettably, no. We had some issues but all that got resolved **somehow** and we're basically hoping it won't start occurring again. Because we have very vague sense of how to kill those issues. And we're uncertain if this question related to that to begin with.